# Add two side buttons to image slideshow

Tags: html, css

I would like to create two buttons for the image slideshow I am creating two buttons that are vertically centered and are stuck to the edges.Like this:

[image]

I have created two buttons in HTML using the following code:

```
<button class="button_left" >"left"</button>
<button class="button_right">"right"</button>
```

I want to make sure that every time a button is pressed it either moves left or right using CSS. I am not sure on how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="slider-holder">
            <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
            <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
            <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
            <div class="image-holder">
                <img src="1.jpg" class="slider-image" />
                <img src="2.jpg" class="slider-image" />
                <img src="3.jpg" class="slider-image" />
    <button class="button_left" >"left"</button>
    <button class="button_right">"right"</button>

            </div>
            <div class="button-holder">
                <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
                <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
                <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>

.slider-holder
        {
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .image-holder
        {
            width: 2400px;
            background-color: red;
            height: 400px;
            clear: both;
            position: relative;

            -webkit-transition: left 2s;
            -moz-transition: left 2s;
            -o-transition: left 2s;
            transition: left 2s;
        }

        .slider-image
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: 0px;
        }

        #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -800px;
        }

        #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -1600px;
        }

        .button-holder
        {
            position: relative;
            top: -20px;
        }

        .slider-change
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: brown;
        }
```

Comment: http://freefrontend.com/css-sliders/

Comment: yes I just figured that out but I don't know how to make the buttons animate the gallery

Comment: its ok don't believe me if you want  but just help please sir

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: ok sir i will add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position:relative` on the parent element.

```
#parent{
 position:relative;
}
```

Then create two `buttons` inside the parent and position them relative to their parent.

```
#left-btn, #right-btn{
 position:absoulte;
 top:50%;
}
#left-btn{
 left:0;
}
#right-btn{
 right:0;
}
```

Example:

```css
#slideshow{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
#left-btn, #right-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 1em);
}
#left-btn{
  left:0;
}
#right-btn{
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id='slideshow'>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" />
  <input id='left-btn' type='button' value='<' />
  <input id='right-btn' type='button' value='>' />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you can u 1+ my question